# JQuery delegate method on a grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates, jquery-events

I am trying to use the delegate method on a grid that I wrap with the DataTables.Net plug-in. I originally had this code which works as expected.

```
    $("#myGrid tbody tr").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).children('td').eq(0).text();
        alert(id);
    });
```

However, if I change the paging size then the newer rows don't have the click event calling the function. I decided the new JQuery delegate method should do exactly what I wanted; however, it does nothing at all on any tr element.

Could anyone explain why this does not work :

```
    $('#myGrid tbody').delegate('tr', 'click', function() {
        var id = $(this).children('td').eq(0).text();
        alert(id);
    });
```

I have tried different combinations of the selector and none get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
$("#myGrid tbody tr").live('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).children('td').eq(0).text();
    alert(id);
});
```

`.live()` works for current of future elements.

Comment: That's exactly what `delegate` is for, except it has better performance, due to less required bubbling of events.

Comment: Thank you guys, I was avoiding 'live' because I thought that delegate was supposed to replace it. I still do not understand why delegate doesn't work for me, but live does and everything is worling as expected. Once again, thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: @Paul it doesn't work because your grid is being replaced.  If you wanted to use delegate you'd have to attach it above the elements that get replaced.  In Alex's example the event is attached to the grid instead of document like live does by default...which this is more efficient as it means fewer bubbles, it doesn't help if that element gets blown away as part of your AJAX load.  That's why it doesn't work in this case...the element listening doesn't exist.  If you had a div on the outside `id="wrapper"`, then this would work: `$('#wrapper').delegate('#myGrid tr','click', function() {...`

Comment: @Alex - While that's normally true, if you're attaching to an element replaced as part of the ajax callback, it's useless.  Whether it's `.live()` with a narrower context or `.delegate()`, either one needs to be on an element that's not being replaced...since I don't know what that is here, `.live()` is the certain option for it working.

Comment: This does everything except answer the question "why is delegate method not working" - confusing that it's selected as the answer. Delegate _does_ replace live. It will likely be deprecated in future versions. It is a better use of event delegation in every facet.

Comment: Nick, thanks for your reply. It makes total sense. And I do have a wrapper that I could have be the high level element. You just have to love Stack Overflow!

Comment: @Nick - agreed, I believe I mentioned that in my answer, that the tbody was likely being manipulated and ruining the delegation.

Comment: @Alex - It wasn't the tbody like you stated, it was the entire table being destroyed, hence the problem.  `#myGrid` is the table.  This is why I clarified what's happening in comments.  If you look at my explanation in the 4th comment, I state exactly *why* it's not working...

Answer (score 15):

Try this instead:

```
$('#myGrid').delegate('tr', 'click', function() {
  var id = $(this).children('td').eq(0).text();
  alert(id);
});
```

There's a good chance that some events on your tbody are getting messed with and/or your tbody's are getting manipulated. I doubt the entire table suffers from this problem as well.

Comment: Note that this could potentially be several times faster than using `live` depending on how your dom is structured.

Answer (score 3):

Behind the scenes, `bind`, `delegate` and `live` all use the method **`on`**.

I've had a few problems with `delegate`, so I started using `on` instead.
Converting your `delegate` calls to `on` is easy: just swap the first and second arguments.

This:

```
 $('#myGrid tbody').delegate('tr', 'click', function() {
        var id = $(this).children('td').eq(0).text();
        alert(id);
    });
```

Becomes this:

```
 $('#myGrid tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
        var id = $(this).children('td').eq(0).text();
        alert(id);
    });
```

BTW: `live` is deprecated in newer version of jQuery

Comment: "on" is available only since 1.7

Comment: "on" doesnt work on iPhone or iPad - neither does live. Delegate works if you delegate the exact element - hence it wont work for ajax updated elements. Its a real headache - and I havent found a good workaround for something as simple as clicking rows in a table that is updated through ajax!

Comment: I've personally used `on` on iphones, ipads and androids 2.3 and 4, and it worked. is it possible that maybe you're not using jQuery on these platforms?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#myGrid tbody').delegate('click', 'tr', function() {
    var id = $(this).children('td').eq(0).text();
    alert(id);
});
```

or

```
$('body').delegate('click', '#myGrid tbody tr', function() {
    var id = $(this).children('td').eq(0).text();
    alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score -4):

If the newer rows are being added dynamically, you have to use `live` method on the items, change the `delegate` to `live`

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `delegate` does--it's just event delegation like `live`.

Comment: `delegate` uses `live` at it's core, however it has better performance than live by using event delegation on a common ancestor that is not the base document.